# Struts 2 with jquery - Convert old style Ajax to jquery Ajax

Tags: jquery, struts2

I have a struts 2 web application which does some old school style Ajax as follows...

Struts.xml

```
    <action name="storeCurrentStatusDialog"
        class="com.mycompany.eposweb.action.StoreCurrentStatusAction"
        method="update">
        <result name="success" type="stream">
            <param name="contentType">text/html</param>
            <param name="inputName">inputStream</param>
        </result>
    </action>
```

Javascript

```
function saveTradingHourUpdates() {
    var url="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/storeCurrentStatusDialog.action?strid="+document.dform.strid.value+"&closingtime="+document.dform.closingtime.value+"&openingtime="+document.dform.openingtime.value+"&businessDt="+document.dform.businessDt.value+"&reason="+document.dform.reason.value;
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest){// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){

        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
            var rp = xmlhttp.responseText;
            $("#dialog-form").html("<div style='text-align:center;padding-bottom:20px'>" + rp +"</div><div style='text-align:center;'><input type='button' value='ok' onclick='closeDialogAndReload()'></div>");
            $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").hide();          
        }
      }
    xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

It works but I am looking to replace the old school Ajax style javascript with jquery style Ajax javascript. Can someone help me with a guide of what the jquery javascript would look like? Also, do I need to change the way the action is defined in the struts.xml file?

Comment: Why was this marked off topic? The person below gave me a very good answer to the question and it helped me a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't need to change the struts.xml file. Your jquery ajax code will looks like this:

```
function saveTradingHourUpdates() {
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  dataType: "html",
  url: "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/storeCurrentStatusDialog.action?strid="+document.dform.strid.value+"&closingtime="+document.dform.closingtime.value+"&openingtime="+document.dform.openingtime.value+"&businessDt="+document.dform.businessDt.value+"&reason="+document.dform.reason.value
})      
.done(function( rp ) {
         $("#dialog-form").html("<div style='text-align:center;padding-bottom:20px'>" + rp +"</div><div style='text-align:center;'><input type='button' value='ok' onclick='closeDialogAndReload()'></div>");
         $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").hide();
 });

}
```